# I need to append div just below textbox dynamically

Tags: javascript

```
Name: <input type="text" id='name'/>
<!-- Here I want to create div when myFunction() is called -->

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>

<script>
function myFunction() {

    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact");
    ele.innerHTML="fffffffffff";
    document.getElementById("name").appendChild(ele);

}

</script>
```

Anything wrong in this JavaScript code.

Comment: what is happening when you run the function, any errors anything created in the DOM?

Comment: no errors. just not getting the innerHTML.

Comment: What result are you expecting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use jQuery. if you want `div` after the input.

```
<script>
   function myFunction(){
       $("#name").after('<div id="timedrpact">fffffffffff</div>');

    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does not work as `appendChild` means that you put the child in the parent, and `<input type="text"><div></div></input>` is invalid.

Instead I think you mean to put the div after the text input, so the simplest solution will be to create an element after the input and append the div to this element, like below.

HTML:

```
Name: <input type="text" id='name'/>
<span id='afterName'></span>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

Javascript:

```
function myFunction() {

    var ele = document.createElement("div");
    ele.setAttribute("id","timedrpact");
    ele.innerHTML="fffffffffff";
    document.getElementById("afterName").appendChild(ele);

}
```

Comment: Thanks but actually I can't put span over there. I am working on some other Application where I need that span should be sent from JavaScript function.

Comment: I need a validation message under text box basically.

Comment: But you want the div to be after the text input right? @user2606112

Note that you can use any element basically, and position it anywhere